# GWT: Generate image from html String  (.png,jpeg)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I have a GWT app that generates an HTML String. I want to convert this String to an image e.g

```
<html>
 <head> </head>    
 <body>
  <several HTML elements including <img too>
 </body>
</html>
```

I tried to using [Html2Image](http://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/) which works when I test it locally in a normal Java code (with a main class)

But when I deploy to Google App Engine (GAE) I get:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.geom.Dimension2D is a restricted class.
 Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.stub.java.awt.geom.Dimension2D.<clinit>(Dimension2D.java)
        at gui.ava.html.image.generator.HtmlImageGenerator.<clinit>(HtmlImageGenerator.java:26)
        at co.za.cre8.web.lottoShop.server.NotificationServiceImpl.geneateImage(NotificationServiceImpl.java:237)
        at co.za.cre8.web.lottoShop.server.NotificationServiceImpl.sendMessage(NotificationServiceImpl.java:181)
```

Pretty clear what the problem is, is there an alternative library?

Thanks in advance.
PB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [conversion API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/conversion/) will handle this for you.

Comment: WOW@! Sounds interesting, will give it a try and let you know. Thanks Nic

Comment: Hi @nick-johnson, I am marking your suggestion as an accepted answer :), I am able to conveniently generate a .png from html string. However my images i.e <img src="www.xyz.com/img/someImge.gif"> is blank. Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks again Nick,I just had a look at my code, Yes I added `http://` According to  [Additional_Functions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/conversion/overview#Additional_Functions) I may need to create Asset for each of the images in the HTML String. When I tried it, (Create a .gif asset with gif's content - byte[] as data ) e.g `Asset e = new Asset("image/gif", loadGIFByte(gifName), gifName);` I get a `CONVERSION PATH ERRROR`. Perhaps I should create my image asset as <img src="http://...> instead of gif byte data? Thanks for any help.

Comment: And by the way Nick, the same HTML content I'm trying to convert to png is sent to via email and it displays correctly as I want it but when converted to png, no image is showing. Image forms 98% of the content I'm trying to convert. You can have a look here [here](http://www.lottoshop.co.za) on the left top corner, you will see widgets loaded of numbers (.gif) images. I'm trying to convert that to a png.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about, how you are receiving the image.

If it is as a file on file system, and if you can use a simple gateway for this purpose, its easy to do it with [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net).

Since its a binary you can keep gateway or a request queue, and constantly produce the image if a request comes.

However, if you are expecting the `BufferedImage` , this may not be the right thing.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your response, I build the html string programmatically and not on file system. on GAE you cannot write to FS.

Comment: you dont need a physical file itself. Cutycapt is a source, edit the source to accept source code and use it.